# Equation of a Rational Function Given Zeros and asymptotes

Tags: functions, rational-functions

Construct a rational polynomial function such that it has zeroes at $x= -2 , 3$ and has vertical asymptotes at $x= 2, -3$ and has a oblique asymptote $y= x-5$.

I found this one

$$=\frac{(x+2)(x-3)}{(x-2)(x+3)}\\
=\frac{x^2-x-6}{x^2+x-6}$$

then I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Here's the [MathJax](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference&ved=2ahUKEwi1qeS9zcnpAhVPwTgGHbbFDBMQFjAAegQIBRAC&usg=AOvVaw1zLdIXv6Cu4GY53kDgHoTt) tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure all of the required properties, consider
$$f(x)=x-5+\frac{p(x)}{(x-2)(x+3)}\,,$$
which has asymptotes in the right places.

To get the zeros at $3$ and $-2$, we need $f(3)=0$ and $f(-2)=0$. These conditions imply $p(3)=12$ and $p(-2)=-28$. Let $p(x)=ax+b$. Then we have $3a+b=12$ and $-2a+b=-28$. Solving simultaneously, we obtain $a=8,b=-12$, so we have
$$f(x)=x-5+\frac{8x-12}{(x-2)(x+3)}\,.$$

Comment: the answer will be a rational function which numerator degree must be higher than denominator cause it has oblique asymptote. And its long division must be x-5

Comment: @NahidulIslam My function $f$ satisfies those properties. It can be written as $\dfrac{x^3-4x^2-3x+18}{x^2+x-6}$ if you prefer.

Comment: can you please explain how you got     x^3 - 4x^2 - 3x + 18

Comment: $x-5+\dfrac{8x-12}{(x-2)(x+3)}=\dfrac{(x-5)(x-2)(x+3)+8x-12}{(x-2)(x+3)}$ and then expand out the brackets.